# Why not open up the table when it is snooker-friendly?

Tags: snooker

Below is shown a position from the famous Fu-Day game of snooker in which Day achieved four snookers. This was aided by the snooker-friendly condition of the balls in a cluster at the end of the table, allowing the cue to be hidden.

Why would Fu not clear the cluster by hitting the brown/green to the side of the table? Obviously it will be a foul, but he would only take one foul penalty and it would make it a lot harder for Day to hide the cue after that.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most situations, not attempting to hit the ball "on" would be a "Foul and a Miss" and the opponent would have the option of having the balls reset to the position before the shot, rendering this tactic worthless:

> The striker shall, to the best of his ability, endeavour to hit the ball on or a
>   ball that could be on after a Red has been potted. If the referee considers
>   the Rule infringed, he shall call FOUL AND A MISS
>
> [...]
>
> After a FOUL AND A MISS has been called, the next player may request
>   the offender to play again from the position left, or at his discretion, from
>   the original position, with all balls being replaced

([Official rules](http://www.wpbsa.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/official-rules-of-the-game.pdf), Section 3, Rule 14 Foul and a Miss). However, my reading of Rule 14 is that "Foul and a Miss" cannot be called if snookers are required:

> If the referee considers the Rule infringed, he shall call FOUL AND A MISS unless:
>
> (i) any player needed penalty points before, or as a result of, the stroke
>   being played;

so Fu could perhaps have done this. On the other hand, there is Section 4, Rule 1:

> In the event of:
>
> [...]
>
> any conduct by a Player which in the opinion of the referee is wilfully
>   or persistently unfair

the referee has the option of awarding the frame to the opponent. I don't know what counts as "wilfully unfair" for world class players.